# Solving A math equation using Java

Tags: java

I have hit a snag in my program when this calculates I get result of 0.0

```
y = 1/6*Math.pow(x,3)+1/2*Math.pow(x,2)-1/3*x;
```

I have tried writing the equation in chunks so I can add the results up after calculation but the result just keeps ending up being 0.0 and I don't know why. Is this a syntactical error or is there a rule that I'm missing about java?.

Comment: `1/6 == 0` and `1/2 == 0` and `1/3 == 0`

Comment: This question can't be generalized there is so many different ways of asking it, and when I asked the question I had no idea where the problem was in the equation so there is no method to asking this quesiton

Answer (score 2):

When you divide two integers Java truncates the result to an integer. If you want a fractional result you need to use floating point numbers. `1/2` is `0`; `1.0/2.0` is `0.5`.

```
y = 1.0/6.0*Math.pow(x,3) + 1.0/2.0*Math.pow(x,2) - 1.0/3.0*x;
```

Comment: Omg thank you so much that worked, I will need to remember that, I still have a lot of things to learn.

Answer (score -1):

```
y = 1/6*Math.pow(x,3)+1/2*Math.pow(x,2)-1/3*x;
```

Here you are doing division of two integers, which would result in 0. Make one/both of the values to decimal (1.0/6.0 etc) and then try this. It should give the correct result. The reason is that, 1/6 will be corrected to the closest `integer` value, which is 0.